# Частота экрана падает до 24Hz

Tags: c, opengl, opengles, sdl2

Частота падает, когда переключаюсь в полноэкранный режим.
Пишу в sdl2 с opengl и opengl es. Вот код, незнаю, может в нем ошибки, так как мой телевизор поддерживает только 60Hz, то и вручную приходиться выставлять 60Hz. Но на других мониторах герц побольше чем в телевизоре. Почему так, раньше вроде бы не замечал такой проблемы. Вот код на всякий случай.

```
    SDL_Init ( SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS );
    SDL_DisplayMode mode;

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 0 );

    SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode ( 0, &mode );
    int width = mode.w;
    int height = mode.h;
    //mode.refresh_rate = 60;

#if 0
    width = 1920;
    height = 1080;
#endif

    global.width = width;
    global.height = height;

#if 1
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1 );
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute ( SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24 );

#endif

    int flags = 0;
    flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
#if defined ( __ANDROID__ )
    flags |= SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN;
#endif
    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow ( "ipsi", 
            0, 0,
            width, height,
            flags );
    SDL_SetWindowDisplayMode ( window, &mode );

    SDL_GLContext glc;
    glc = SDL_GL_CreateContext ( window );
    SDL_GL_MakeCurrent ( window, glc );
```

Comment: Попробуйте откатиться на SDL 2.0.8. На 2.0.9 сообщают о проблемах с производительностью.

Comment: О спасибо, помогло, а откуда вы узнали о сообщениях?

Comment: @HolyBLackCat, а как мне скачать 2.0.8 версию исходников, чтобы для android создать?

Comment: Да просто попадались похожие вопросы здесь и на англоSO. *"как мне скачать 2.0.8 версию исходников"* В ссылке на новые исходники поправьте `9` на `8`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как с помощью hg это сделать, у них там mercurial и написаны tags и версии разные, и я не пойму как с помощью hg можно получить ветку с 2.0.8, а так я скачал уже по вашему совету архив. Но интересно как с помощью hg можно сделать.

Comment: Вот честно, не знаю. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я посмотрел, вроде бы так можно получить ветку. hg clone http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL -r release-2.0.8